# Assimp processing a node

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

For some reason my script for processing the bone hierarchy only finds **max two children** for a bone, and ignores the rest. I can't seem to pinpoint what I'm doing wrong in my script. The `GetNode` function seems to run only two times even if `mNumChildren`is more than two.

```
void GetNode(aiNode *node) {
    string name = (string)node->mName.data;
    //Third child does not get putput
    cout << name << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++) {
        node = node->mChildren[i];
        GetNode(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but that you seem to need a C-style cast in your code is a big red flag. Why do you need that cast? What is `node->mName.data`?

Comment: That how the nodes should be parsed according to [Assimp's documentation](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_node.html)

Comment: Just to nitpick, the `mName` member is an `aiString`, who has a member named `data` that is an array containing a null-terminated byte string. Which is basically what `std::string` wraps. So no cast needed. Like I said, C-style casts are a bad sign, even if it's part of the documentation of a commonly used library.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood you, had way too little sleep. Right I shouldn't had added string cast there, and in no way is this recommended in documentation hahah. Changed it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing `node = node->mChildren[i]; GetNode(node)` to `GetNode(node>mChildren[i])` seemed to fix it. However I am not sure why.

Comment: While this seems to solve your problem, I think you should take a long night sleep, and when fully rested do some research about why, and what the difference might be (perhaps even look at the generated code to find some possible difference). Step through the code (possibly also on assembly level), and when you figured out what the difference is then please come back and update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are traversing in a depth-first manner.  You could try iterating children first in a breadth-first manner by,

```
for (auto node : node->mChildren) {
    std::cout << node->mName.data << "\n";
}
for (auto node : node->mChildren) {
    GetNode(node);
}
```